# Normal Map only visible on single Shape Key?

Tags: mesh, baking, shape-keys, normal-map

Is there a way to make a normal map for facial wrinkles more/less visible with certain shape keys? I've seen something like this on youtube, but I haven't been able to determine how it was done.

I've got a character that I want to give big smile wrinkles, but I don't want the character's basis to be that smile. So the smile wrinkles shouldn't be visible until the shape-key I specify.

Thanks.

Comment: You could drive the normal map intensity with the value of the shapekey.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The keyword "drive" rings a bell haha. I haven't explored using drivers yet, but I guess that must be how you accomplish this! Thanks! There should be YouTube tutorials that cover drivers.

Answer (score 2):

As Scott commented you can drive the Normal Map strength with the value of the shapekey. Right click with your mouse the Value of your shape key and select Copy as New Driver.

[image: Copy as New Driver]

Next, right click the Strength value of you Normal Map node and select Paste Driver.

[image: Paste Driver]

Now the strength of the normal map changes as you change the value of the shape key.

[image: Result]